# Lambda Function does not compile in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-c++-2010

I am more interested in knowing WHY it does not compile than fixing the code.

fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

```
int main()
{
    class MyClass
    {
    public:
        MyClass(const std::string & name)
            : name_(name) {}
        std::string name_;
    };

    auto creator = []() -> MyClass *
    {
        return new MyClass("Hello World");
    };

    MyClass * pMyClass = creator();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

Anytime you see an internal compiler error, you're looking at a bug in the compiler itself. Basically, the compiler didn't give a compiler error; it *crashed*.

In these cases, there is no "why" as far as when they occur (not unless it was running out of resources). Or at least, not one that is easily determinable. Your best bet is to try to rearrange the code to make the compiler behave.

If you're not using VC2010 SP1, upgrade to the service pack and try again.

Comment: @aCuria: If it's still happening with SP1, you should file a bug report on Microsoft Connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 3):

As another data point, the 64-bit version of the VS 2010 compiler doesn't crash, but it gives this error instead:

```
test.cpp(16) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MyClass'
```

If the `class MyClass` definition is moved outside of `main()`, both the x86 and x64 compilers will work.

Clearly, the x86 compiler crashing is a bug.  I believe that using the local `MyClass` type should be fine in a lambda (and GCC 4.6.1 with `-std=gnu++0x` has no problem with it), so I think the error that the x64 compiler is throwing is also a bug.

<strike>I don't have access to VS 11 Dev Preview at the moment to test if the problem is still there.</strike>

VS 11 Dev Preview (cl.exe version 17.00.40825.2) has no problem with the local `MyClass` type being used in the lambda.